# How to convert Psd to psf?

Tags: adobe, photoshop

I have PSD document but my client requires the file in .psf format.Is there any way to convert PSD file to PSf file? Desperately need help.

Comment: What do you mean by PSf file. A `.psf` is a [Photoshop Proof Settings File](https://fileinfo.com/extension/psf) and is used for color management settings, so it's not possible to convert a `.psd` to `.psf`. One is an image file format (`.psd`), and the  other is a settings file (`.psf`).

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather strange request from a client, but I suppose there may be circumstances calling for such arcane undertakings.

Check this: https://fileinfo.com/extension/psf

Then locate that file, package and send.

RobC is correct in his comment. If I were you, I would research ICC (International Colour Consortium) processes. This is standard tools if you work in a (precision) print environment. The general thinking regarding screens (in my neck of the woods anyway) is that there is no colour control on the consumer side (meaning that screens produce varying colour results) and so don't bother with precision — just get it close.

If you want to comment on the specific end-use environment, we can respond to that.